# Flutter Missing Purpose String in Info.plist, Missing Push Notificatoion Entitlement

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to upload my flutter app build to app store connect and test it through testflight.
But the App Store Connect sent me a mail that my app has problem.

The Two Problem:

```
ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - NSCameraUsageDescription
```

```
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement
```

The strange thing is, I don't use NSCamera and Push Notification.
Before, I got more Isseus because of `permission_handler`. But I removed All permissions in `PodFile` as I don't use it.

Libraries I use:

```
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  lottie: ^1.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  image: ^3.0.1
#  photo_view: ^0.10.3
  photo_view:
    path: ./photo_view-master
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: 7.1.6
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.9+1
  package_info: ^2.0.0
  flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.4.0
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.7
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  permission_handler: ^6.1.0
  share: '>=0.6.5+4 <2.0.0'
  social_share_plugin:
    path: ./social_share_plugin-master
    #0.3.1 + 1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  firebase_crashlytics: ^1.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  apple_sign_in_firebase:
    path: ./apple_sign_in_firebase
  in_app_purchase: ^0.5.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0+3
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
```

my PodFile for `permission_handler` remove unused permission:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
            '$(inherited)',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
            'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
            'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
            'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
            'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
            'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
            'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
            'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

            ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
            'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
            'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
            'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
            'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
            'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=0'
          ]

        end
  end
end
```

How can I solve this and get successful upload to App Store Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is works in my case.

Add the Permission info.
[image]

And Push notification entry in iOS code.
[image]

Comment: did you set flag 0 in pod file as well? 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0', 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0', etc